# Catching WCF exceptions on the UI side

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I am trying to figure out the best way to catch WCF exceptions on the UI side.

First, I have to say that **I still do use a `using` block** when calling my service methods, because my client proxies all implement the `IDisposable.Dispose` method, like this :

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (State != CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to use a `using` block in my client code, because at the end of the using block, the Dispose method checks the state of the communication channel upon disposing and aborts the channel if it is on the faulted state.

I have read a lot of articles about catching exceptions on the UI side and actually, my code looks like this :

```
using (var myClientProxy = new MyClientProxy())
{
    try
    {
        myClientProxy.DoSomething();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException timeoutException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            timeoutException.Message, 
            "Timeout expired", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MesssageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    catch (FaultException<ServiceErrorDetails> faultException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            faultException.Detail.Message, 
            "A service exception occured", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    catch (CommunicationException communicationException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            communicationException.Message, 
            "Communication problem", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            exception.Message, 
            "An exception occured", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is very redundant, and, because I have multiple WCF calls from the UI, this can become a quite big code smell.

I would like to be able to catch **anything** that can go bad in the service call in a **single** catch block and show a message box to the user.

Is it good practice ? Because, even if I reduce the code to a single try/catch block, wouldn't that still be a code smell ?

How can I handle that better ?

Comment: as far as eliminating the multiple catch blocks goes: since they all inherit from `System.Exception,` you can leave just the last block and go check within the catch scope if the caught (general) `Exception` is of a certain kind and respond accordingly. That being said: it is cleaner? In my opinion, no. I still prefer the multiple catch blocks since it increases code readability and readability always justifies a few extra lines in my book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **policy** of how to handle and show an exception is implemented in this **ShowException** method

```
private void ShowException(Exception ex)
{
    string title ;

    if(ex is TimeoutException)
    {
        title = "Timeout expired" ;
    }
    else if(ex is FaultException)
    {
        title = "A service exception occured" ;
    }
    else if(ex is CommunicationException)
    {
        title = "Communication problem" ;
    }
    else
    {
        title = "An exception occured" ;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, title,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MesssageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

And then in any method of your code you used it like this

```
private void AnyMethod()
{
    ....
    using (var myClientProxy = new MyClientProxy())
    {
        try
        {
            myClientProxy.DoSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowException(ex) ;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

If you ever feel like using logging and modifying how to handle the exceptions you only need to change the **ShowException** method

Comment: That is a good idea. Since I have to handle WCF exceptions the same in many UI classes, would it be even better to create a static helper class which contains the error handling method ?

Comment: @JoanLeaven as long as they are all being catched on the UI side, sure. Helpers/Utility clases are very usefull and end up being reused in other projects

Comment: Then, I wouldn't be forced to create the try/catch block INSIDE the using block but once for all the method code, right ? That way I could catch everything that could happen inside the WCF method call as well as everything else that happens in the same method ?

Comment: @JoanLeaven feel free to expermient with the code I provided and adjust it to what you see helps you the most

Answer (score 0):

If you create a method to do your trying and catching, you can reuse that method...

```
public void TryServiceCall(Action work)
{
  try
  {
    work();
  }
  catch1...
  catch2...
  catch3...
  catch4...
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
using (var myClientProxy = new MyClientProxy())
{
  TryServiceCall(myClientProxy.DoSomething);
}

using (var myClientProxy = new MyClientProxy())
{
  int result;
  TryServiceCall( () => result = myClientProxy.GetFavoriteNumber() );
}
```